# Evaluate $\int_{C[0,3]} \frac{\exp(z)}{(z+2)^2\sin(z)} dz$ Using Residue Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

$\displaystyle \int_{C[0,3]} \frac{\exp(z)}{(z+2)^2\sin(z)} \, dz$ using Residue Theorem.

I have found singularities within $C[0,3]$, which are $-2$ and $0$. For $z=-2$, it is a pole with degree $2$. However, I do not know what kind of singularities $z=0$ is.

Comment: The zeroes of $sin(z)$ are simple.

Comment: (and you need the residue of the pole at $z=2$)

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 Then how to evaluate $Res(f,0)=\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{exp(z)}{z(z+2)^2\sin(z)}$? The denominator becomes zero.

Comment: @user1952009 Why z=2 is also a pole?

Comment: @Kenneth.K first where did that extra $z$ come from in the denominator? Its not in the original integrand, and the residue formula (in this case) is $\lim_{z\to 0} z\cdot f(z)$.

Comment: at $z = -2$  a typo, what I meant was that you need to compute (and understand) what is the residue of a pole of order $n$

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 Oh yes. That's a typo. So then to get the residue at z=0, I just need to evaluate the limits of $zf(z)$ as z goes to 0?

Comment: @user1952009 Understood. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah in general if $f(z)$ has a pole of order $n$ at $z_0$ then the residue is given by $Res(f,z_0)=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\lim_{z\to z_0} (z-z_0)^n \frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}} f(z)$.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 : I prefer much more "it is given by the coef $c_{-1}$ of the Laurent series at the pole" (which reduces to what you wrote)

Comment: @user1952009 I actually agree. What you gave I consider the actual definition of residues. The formula I gave is just a (sometimes) convenient way to compute them and is given by a theorem. At least none of my books define it with the limit formula, they always define it with that particular coefficient of the Laurent series and then prove the theorem... do you think its easier to compute the Laurent series in this case though or take the limit? (I am seriously asking not a patronizing question!)

Comment: I think doing the Laurent series is much easier than taking the limit in this case since the limit is a bit complicated.

Comment: @Dr.MV ah yes very elementary for one who knows asymptotic analysis :) thank you! Sorry for being obtuse everybody :P

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 Now you're just being "acute."  ;-)) And a vote up for your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the specific issue raised in the OP, the pole at $z=0$ is a simple pole since $\sin(z)=z(1+O(z^2))$ and therefore $\frac{1}{\sin(z)}=\frac{1}{z(1+O(z^2))}=\frac{1}{z}+O(1)$

Now, as stated in the comments, there are a number of ways forward to determining the residue at $z=-2$.

**METHODOLGY $1$:**  Apply Standard Limit Formula

First, we can apply the [Limit Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Limit_formula_for_higher_order_poles) for evaluating the residue at at a pole of order $n$ and write for $n=2$

$$\begin{align}
\text{Res}\left(\frac{e^z}{(z+2)^2\sin(z)}, z=-2\right)&=\lim_{z\to -2}\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{e^z}{\sin(z)}\right)\\\\
&\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{=-e^{-2}\frac{1+\cot(2)}{\sin(2)}} \tag 1
\end{align}$$

---

**METHODOLGY $2$:**  Find the Coefficient on $\frac{1}{z+2}$ of the Laurent Series

Second, we can determine the coefficient of the $(z+2)^{-1}$ term in the Laurent series for the integrand.  We proceed by expanding the numerator and denominator in their Taylor series to reveal that

$$\begin{align}
\frac{e^z}{(z+2)^2\sin(2)}&=\frac{e^{-2}\left(1+(z+2)+O(z+2)^2\right)}{(z+2)^2\left(\sin(-2)+\cos(-2)(z+2)+O(z+2)^2\right)}\\\\
&=-\frac{e^{-2}}{\sin(2)}\frac{\left(1+(z+2)+O(z+2)^2\right)\left(1+\cot(2)(z+2)+O(z+2)^2\right)}{(z+2)^2}\\\\
&=-\frac{e^{-2}}{\sin(2)}\left(\frac{1}{(z+2)^2}+\frac{1+\cot(2)}{z+2}+O(1)\right)
\end{align}$$

Inasmuch as the residue is the coefficient on the $\frac{1}{z+2}$ term, we find that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\text{Res}\left(\frac{e^z}{(z+2)^2\sin(z)}, z=-2\right)=-e^{-2}\frac{1+\cot(2)}{\sin(2)}}$$

recovering the result reported in $(1)$!